# how to support range subscripting in swift

Tags: swift, range, subscript

How do you support range subscripting in swift?

```
struct MyStruct<T> : SequenceType
{
  var components : [T]
  subscript(index:Int) -> T {
    return components[index]
   }

  func generate() -> GeneratorOf<T> {
    var index : Int = 0
    return GeneratorOf<T> {
      return (index < self.components.length) ? self.components[index++] : nil
    } 
  }
}
```

This works fine:

```
for component in myStruct {}
component[2]
```

But how do you get this to work?

```
   for component in components[1...5] {}
```

Comment: Look at how Array does it. There's another `subscript` declaration: `subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> Slice<T>`

Comment: I think that the thread that I linked to should answer your question. If not, please let me know and I will reopen the question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.  Should I delete this question?